# Checking if a user is in a role in asp.net mvc Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I'm having an issue seeding my database with users and roles.

The User and the Role are both created (I can see them in the database after the error is thrown).

However, when I try to check if the user is in a role, I get an exception.

My code is:

```
    public class tbInitializer<T> : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<tbContext>
    {
    protected override void Seed(tbContext context)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext userscontext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(userscontext);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

        var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(userscontext);
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);


        if(!userscontext.Users.Any(x=> x.UserName=="marktest"))
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "marktest", Email = "marktest@gmail.com" };
            userManager.Create(user, "Pa$$W0rD!");
        }

        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
        { 
            roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
        }

        if(!userManager.IsInRole("marktest","Admin"))
        { 
            userManager.AddToRole("marktest","Admin");
        }
```

However, on the line:

`if(!userManager.IsInRole("marktest","Admin"))`

An exception is thrown with the error: `UserId not found.`

The User and the Role are both in the database when I check after the exception is thrown:

[image: Shows User Added to DB]

[image: Shows Role Added to DB]

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: Have you tried `SaveChanges()` before `if(!userManager.IsInRole("marktest","Admin"))`?

Comment: Hi - yes, I added `context.SaveChanges();` - just before that line, but is still throws an exception with the same error.  Thanks, Mark

Comment: Is "marktest" user saved in a database then?

Comment: Hi - yes, I've added screenshots to the question.  Thanks again, Mark

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I found out the solution, in case anyone else is having this problem.

The "IsInRole" is expecting a User.Id - not a UserName string - so I changed to:

```
            if (!userManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Admin"))
            {
                userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
            }
```

So the working code becomes:

```
    ApplicationDbContext userscontext = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(userscontext);
    var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

    var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(userscontext);
    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

    // Create Role
    if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
    { 
        roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
    }

    if(!userscontext.Users.Any(x=> x.UserName=="marktest"))
    {
        // Create User
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "marktest", Email = "marktest@gmail.com" };
        userManager.Create(user, "Pa$$W0rD!");

        // Add User To Role
        if (!userManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Admin"))
            {
                userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
            }


    }
```

I hope that helps,

Mark

Comment: My code looks the same yet I still get the UserId not found in the same place

Comment: Just a heads-up in case anyone else trips up - haven't check the sync method, but the `userManager.IsInRole` method takes a **user**, not a string for the id.

Answer (score 19):

Simplest thing in life;

```
bool isAdmin= User.IsInRole("admin")
```

Comment: For some reason, this does not work for me! I'm using .Net Core with JWT Authentication.

Comment: try using @if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Model.UserName, "Administrator")) if it works

Comment: J86, for this to work with JWT Authentication, you have to add the roles in the Tokens ClaimsIdentity first, as explained in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036810/asp-net-core-jwt-mapping-role-claims-to-claimsidentity

Answer (score 0):

To add to Mark's post above in its still pretty much the same in .NET Core 3.1 Identity only difference with the async method IsInRoleAsync you have to pass in the IdentityUser type object:

```
var userInRole = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role);
```

Then you can apply your logic afterwards (in my case I was doing two things, first checking the role actually exists and then checking if the user isn't already assigned to that role).