# bearer is for the authentication token but is for a different token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, security

for my MEVN application i am using jwt tokens and i am learning how to send the authentcation tokens via axios. i was told that it is standard practice to put "Bearer " before the token and have the server slice of "Bearer " to read the token's body. but what if i have 2 tokens? the first token is for users, but the 2nd one is for a special account that manages the application. to make life simple i programmed 2 user systems in my application. 1 for regular users and the other for admins. what do i put in front of the admin account token?

example jwt token string that gets passed to server:

```
Bearer cdsklfj2...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bearer` in Authorization header is simply to tell the server that it's an API token, it has nothing to do with the permission for the user or which user is it.

To distinguish between user roles, you can put roles on your JWT payload. For example, if you [decode this token](https://jwt.io/):

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjEyMywicm9sZXMiOlsiQURNSU4iLCJOT1JNQUxfVVNFUiJdfQ.u0YXpuJkQ08RBb4_s6yVeGT3Ua21ptUbXvrzopG-txI
```

you will see that it has `userId` and `roles` in the payload, where `userId` is the user id for that token, and `roles` are the permission the user has.

So on your express app, you can do something like this:

```js
try {
    const payload = verifyToken(jwtToken);
} catch (err) {
    // assuming if the verification failed because of invalid token will throw an error
    return res.status(401).send(); // Unauthorized
}

// Check from roles array if it has "ADMIN" in it
if ( payload.roles.includes("ADMIN") ) {
    adminOnlyFunction(); // Function that can be accessed by admin only
    return res.status(200).send();
} else {
    // If user has no ADMIN roles, return 403 instead
    return res.status(403).send(); // Forbidden
}
```

But there is a drawback when using this method especially if the JWT token is long lived, let's say userId 1 have ADMIN permission, and before the token expired, you decided that userId 1 is no longer an admin, userId 1 will still be able to call `adminOnlyFunction()` since the roles information is stored in the JWT payload. You can prevent this by blacklisting the token when you change the user's permission.

I personally wouldn't put `roles` in the JWT payload, but instead store the user's roles information on your database, and check the roles every time an user sent a request to your server, you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53527119/12397250) on why you shouldn't put roles on your JWT, and the better way of doing it. At the end, it will always depends on your use case.

Comment: You can also use a userinfo endpoint like in the OAuth : https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/signing-in-with-google/verifying-the-user-info/, https://connect2id.com/products/server/docs/api/userinfo). So the roles are managed by your IAM solution and not your software. You app need to call it to know the user role/grade/whatever (store the userinfo in a localstorage if necessary).

Comment: Also, I do not understand `decodeJwtWithYourPrivateKey` : a JWT token can be decoded without key, it is just base64 encoded. But you can verify it if according to a private signature, it is different :) But your framework or IAM should verify it, you do not have to do that manually.

Comment: You are correct, `verifyToken` would be the better method name for that, edited.