# How to populate JWT claims dynamically so policies can be used in controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

In a new API app, going to use JWT bearer tokens for authorization. Idea of storing roles(claims) inside a token great, but there is some issues with using it like this:

[Is setting Roles in JWT a best practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224931/is-setting-roles-in-jwt-a-best-practice)

In our case, main problem would be payload size (100s of roles)

So, we decided to load roles on every request (DB call). However, I am not sure where in execution pipeline this should happen? We would like to use Policies and other built in ASP.NET Core functionality. Somewhere in pipeline we need to place a code to load claims from DB for a user, but before controller executed and policies checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something similar, I check the user has the required permission on each request. Mine is done based on Features, but you can change it a bit to be based on Roles.

I have a `User` with 1 `Role`, and then Role has `N` Features.

For this I use created my own `AuthorizationHandler` as follows. AuthorizationHandlers are at the start of the pipeline, so it will go through all AuthorizationHandlers before hitting the controller endpoint. Offical Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

'IFeaturesProvider': is just my Business layer to retrieve features from DB.

`ICustomUserContext`: Is a wrapper around `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User` (I will post it at the end of answer for clarity.)

```
public class FeatureRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string FeatureName { get; set; }

    public FeatureRequirement(string featureName)
    {
        FeatureName = featureName;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Authorisation based on Feature.
/// A user is assigned a Role, a role can have N Features.
/// If the user is not assigned the Feature required to access the Controller Action this will throw an Authorisation Error -
/// </summary>
public class FeatureAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<FeatureRequirement>
{
    private readonly IFeaturesProvider _featuresProvider;
    private readonly ICustomUserContext _userContext;

    public FeatureAuthorizationHandler([FromServices] IFeaturesProvider featuresProvider,
        [FromServices] ICustomUserContext userContext)
    {
        _featuresProvider = featuresProvider;
        
        _userContext = userContext;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, FeatureRequirement requirement)
    {
        // Authentication of user failed - Means Token expired or Token incorrect BUT Token exists in Header
        if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        // get the logged in user id and user type
        var userId = _userContext.UserId;
        var userType = _userContext.UserType;

        // get features assigned to currently logged in user
        var userFeatures = _featuresProvider.GetFeaturesByUserId(userId, userType);

        // check if user has the required feature assigned to it's Role
        if (userFeatures.Select(s => s.Name).Contains(requirement.FeatureName))
            context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Then in `Startup.cs` you want to regiseter all your feature/roles as a permission.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // load all features from DB
    var features = rolesProvider.GetAllFeatures(validationContainer);

    // Add policy foreach feature in DB
    foreach (var feature in features)
    {
        options.AddPolicy(feature.Name, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new FeatureRequirement(feature.Name)));
    }
});
```

Also in `Startup`, register your Depency Injection for the `AuthorizationHandler`

```
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, FeatureAuthorizationHandler>();
```

Then in controller you can just do:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "View Asset Driver")]
public class AssetDriversController : BaseController
{
```

where "View Asset Driver" is the name of one of my features.

OR

```
[Authorize(Policy = "View Asset Driver")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAssetDrivers(int companyId, int assetId)
```

Here is the `ICustomUserContext`:

```
   public interface ICustomUserContext
{
    ClaimsPrincipal CurrentUser { get; }
    int UserId { get; }
    UserTypeEnum UserType { get; }
    int ResellerId { get; }
    int CompanyId { get; }
    int DriverId { get; }
}

 public class CustomUserContextAdapter : ICustomUserContext
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

        public CustomUserContextAdapter(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            _accessor = accessor;
        }

        public ClaimsPrincipal CurrentUser => _accessor.HttpContext.User;
        public int UserId => CurrentUser != null ? CurrentUser.GetUserIdInternal() : 0;
        public UserTypeEnum UserType => CurrentUser != null ? CurrentUser.GetUserTypeInternal() : UserTypeEnum.User;
        public int ResellerId => CurrentUser != null ? CurrentUser.GetResellerIdInternal() : 0;
        public int CompanyId => CurrentUser != null ? CurrentUser.GetCompanyIdInternal() : 0;
        public int DriverId => CurrentUser != null ? CurrentUser.GetDriverIdInternal() : 0;
    }
```