# Manually Adding Spring Security Authorities to a Google JWT

Tags: java, angular, spring, google-cloud-platform

The Google Sign-on API generates a JWT that I can use to authenticate a user with Spring Security OAuth2 resource server. The JWT alone will not allow me to use annotation like `@PreAuthorize`, however, because the Google JWT doesn't contain scope or roles attributes. Thus the JwtAuthenticationToken authorities are an empty list.

How do I manually add a `List<SimpleGrantedAuthority>` of authorities to a JwtAuthenticationToken during authentication? Can I manually track a User entity's Roles myself in a database?

### I think I need to make changes here

```
package com.example.ressource_server.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity.oauth2ResourceServer( r-> r.jwt(jwtConfigurer -> jwtConfigurer.jwkSetUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs")));
        httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated());
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: What library are you using to authenticate the JWT on the backend?

Answer (score 1):

Configure Spring Security to protect your endpoints based on the extracted user roles. You can use the `@PreAuthorize` annotation or configure security rules in your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/secure-endpoint").hasRole("ROLE_USER")
                .antMatchers("/admin-endpoint").hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
            .oauth2Login()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Above we are using `hasRole` to restrict access to specific roles. Make sure you match the role names extracted from the JWT token with the roles defined in your security configuration.

Comment: I have already logged in using acces token of google but it doesn't have authoroties claim how can I add them

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't put the roles inside the JWT. When you add data that isn't immutable what will happen if a users role is changed? When will you update the JWT that doesn't live on your server? You'll have to add some updating logic and code that checks for new roles every time the user comes back. Its possible to do so using the claims MJM mentioned in his answer, but it has serious drawbacks if role changes are something of value in your application. See this for a debate on the subject -> [Is setting Roles in JWT a best practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224931/is-setting-roles-in-jwt-a-best-practice)

**A more robust design (IMO)**

The JWT is saving you round trips to the DB by not using cookie lookups but that doesn't mean put everything into it. Put the mutable data, like roles, in the DB and use the userId from the JWT to lookup the roles. If you're willing to learn a very standardized and popular framework then I suggest Spring Security. It comes with a lot of security tools like "Remember me" and lots of tutorials and videos online. It has support for JWT integration and roles. You can mark your controllers with what roles are allowed to access them and behind the scenes it will handle the authorization / error redirection for you....If you decide to still put roles in the JWT then just search your SDK for "claims" to add custom properties to your jwt then use the Spring Security JWT integration so you can protect your controllers like in the example below.

**Spring Security Example**

```
@Controller
@Secured("ROLE_SAMURAI")
class AdminController
```

**Reference Material**

This site is a good start. They have many other Spring Security tutorials -> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

Comment: can I retrieve the roles from database and send it to angular to secure endpoints is it secure or not and how should I do that :)

Comment: Yes to both questions. Your spring application can retrieve the users role from the database and return it at some endpoint like "/user-role". Or just include it in the users session info that you load on every page. You can also have angular retrieve it as an ajax request to something like "/user-info". Your controller at that endpoint can do the database lookup. Theres a lot of ways to do it since the users role is just another piece of database info like an email address. You would typically have a table dedicated to roles.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself, which I solved by manually tracking the JWT user's roles in the application database and creating a custom JwtAuthenticationConverter.

Per the [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction)

> For more flexibility, the DSL supports entirely replacing the converter with any class that implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken>:

You can find Spring's default JwtAuthenticationConverter [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/oauth2/oauth2-resource-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/authentication/JwtAuthenticationConverter.java) and you can extend your `SecurityFilterChain` to use a custom converter like this:

```
http
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                    .jwt(jwt -> jwt
                            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(customJwtAuthenticationConverter())
                    )
            )
```

Where `customJwtAuthenticationConverter` is a `@Bean` e.g.

```
@Bean
Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> customJwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    return new CustomJwtAuthenticationConverter();
}
```

From here, I would start with `CustomJwtAuthenticationConverter` being the same as the `JwtAuthenticationConverter` Spring uses, then modify it to set the `Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities` from your database. My implementation looked like this:

```
User user = ValidateGoogleAuthToken.verifyGoogleAuthToken(jwt.getTokenValue())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Failed to validate JWT."));
    Optional<User> isAlreadyEnabledUser = userRepository.findByUsernameAndEnabledIsTrue(user.getUsername());

    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = List.of();

    if (isAlreadyEnabledUser.isPresent()) {
        User existingEnabledUser = isAlreadyEnabledUser.get();
        authorities = existingEnabledUser.getRoles().stream().map(role ->
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name())
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

If you want to view my source code, it's built into a full-stack Angular/Spring Boot/PostgreSQL demo application with the `.oauth2ResourceServer` entry point [here](https://github.com/pjl-software/full-stack-auth-repo/blob/master/spring-back-end/pjl-application/pjl-application-core/src/main/java/com/pjlsoftware/configurations/SecurityConfig.java#L72) and I walk through the code on YouTube [here](https://youtu.be/VOXno44nCkA).

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract authorities using the default converter
2. Manually add authorities based on your custom logic
3. Combine the default and custom authorities

Then, you need to configure this custom converter in your security configuration.