# Asp.Net Core jwt token is transformed after authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, openid-connect

I have Cognito id token with `email` claim.

```
  ..........
  "iat": 164456734,
  "jti": "81ac2634-e241-444f-88cf-eabf454644",
  "email": "david@mail.com"
}
```

However, after asp net core jwt middleware authentication email claim is transformed from `email` type to `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress` - `ClaimTypes.Email` in C#.

But then I read the token manually:

```
var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(jwtToken);
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(token.Claims);
var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity)
```

Claim type is not transformed and remains `email`.

Why in asp net core authentication claim is transformed to `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress`?

Can I create `claimsPrincipal` manually having this `email` claim transformation without manually modifying `Claims` list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has in fact been understood as `ClaimTypes.Email`, however the string returned by this property is `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress` ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes.email?view=netframework-4.8)).

The token is not transformed, unless specifically done so, rather parsed and understood as `ClaimTypes.Email` with the actual token not modified.

Comment: Is there a way to parse the token manually the same way as it is done by the middleware?

Comment: There is a default claim type mapping that you can clear/modify: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50523668/1658906 (see Startup.cs).

Answer (score 3):

So, Microsoft and OpenIDConnect have different opinions for what the email claim name should be and to disable this remapping you can do either:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // By default, Microsoft has some legacy claim mapping that converts
    // standard JWT claims into proprietary ones. This removes those mappings.
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultOutboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();



    // Or set this flag to false
    .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
    {
        ...
        opt.MapInboundClaims = false;
    });
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging JwtBearer Claim Problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/06/02/debugging-jwtbearer-claim-problems-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Thanks for this post, "opt.MapInboundClaims = false;" helped me :-)